# susbtantially editing an accepted answer

Tags: discussion, editing

Regarding [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20893/how-does-a-switch-know-where-to-route-packet-when-there-is-another-switch-in-fr/20894#20894), or rather the accepted answer:

I feel the answer, while accepted is not so good because of the incorrect use of the broadcasting term instead of flooding (and some minor other points, see the edit I proposed)

Since:
 - the answer is quite old
 - the user [Hal](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/users/4634/hal) is not active for several month now
 - this question was the sole activity of the original poster, [sh4kesbeer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/users/17502/sh4kesbeer)

I feel that there's very few chance that any of them edit the answer or change its status or accept another one instead, and there's a need to correct the answer since an accepted answer should be right and not misleading.

So my question is : is it ok to substantially edit another user accepted answer?

Edit : right now I'm ok to do so because anyway the edit must be reviewed before approval, and I really trust the moderators, but one day my edit may not pass trough moderation and I wouldn't like to abuse this privilege.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substantial edits (those which change the basic meaning/intent) are generally frowned upon.

In this particular case, post another answer and include details of why you think the accepted answer is incorrect. "Accepted" simply means the OP feels it helped/answered their question; It does not imply "correct".

Also, there are badges for (I forget the wording) posting an answer late, and having it up-vote-out-score the accepted answer. Some sort of "turn-around come from behind" badge, for just this scenario.